# How to use Apply() and self defined function to change data in DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

What is the easiest way to make some changes in the index column of different rows in a DataFrame ?

```
def fn(country):
    if any(char.isdigit() for char in country):
        return country[:-2]
    else:
        return country 

df.loc["Country"].apply(fn,axis=1)
```

Comment: Please add a snippet of data

Answer (score 0):

I cant test now. Can you try: `df['Country'] = df.apply(lambda row: fn(row),axis = 1)` and change your function argument to take the row into account (like `row['Country']`). This way you can manipulate anything you want row by row using other column values.